# Cannot find package (pymol)

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I'm trying to install the program pymol (https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/pymol/) on my system (I have Ubuntu 13.04).

I've tried it via this link to the softwarecentre and via the terminal using sudo apt-get install pymol. However, it always says that it cannot find the package.

Comment: Have you enabled the universe repository? http://askubuntu.com/a/148645/53508

Comment: Yes I have, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Visit [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481354/how-to-solve-unable-to-locate-package-error/481355#481355).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can install it via Software Center(GUI tool).
As following steps.

[image]

[image]

Or If you use the command that "apt-get install pymol", first you must use following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

Comment: Also visit [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/481354/how-to-solve-unable-to-locate-package-error/481355#481355).